# Group by week and show even week that doesn't have any data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have query that pulls data by week and groups it together. But it does not display weeks that doesn't have any data. I want show all weeks even if they don't have data as null maybe

Here is the query if someone can help me with this it will awesome

```
    with calender_cte as (
     select convert(date, '2020-01-01') as startdate, convert(date, '2020-02-01') as enddate
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
     from calender_cte cc
     where startdate < enddate     
)
SELECT 
       min(Type) as Type,
       DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), -1) as 'WeekOf',
       DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), +5) as 'to',
       ISNULL(DATEPART(wk, inst.StartDate), 0) as 'WeekNumber',
       Sum(CASE When Type='Outage' Then (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, inst.StartDate,inst.EndDate)) Else 0 End) as 'OutageInMinutes',
       Sum(CASE When Type='Degradation' Then (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, inst.StartDate,inst.EndDate)) Else 0 End) as 'DegradationInMinutes'
FROM calender_cte cc LEFT JOIN
     [DESOutage].[dbo].[OPSInterruption] inst
     ON CC.startdate >=  inst.startdate and CC.startdate <= inst.enddate
Group by DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), -1),
         ISNULL(DATEPART(wk, cc.StartDate), 0),
         DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), +5)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

*****************Output*****************

As you could see week 2 and 4 is missing out since there is no data being returned. I would still like to see week 2 and 4 in the output with maybe 0 as result. Also now when I update the query based on suggestions below i am not getting any data even though I am getting dates and week number

[image]

Data that should be retuned:
[image]

Comment: Did you search for `[tsql] missing week`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive cte to generate calendar dates:

```
with calender_cte as (
     select convert(date, '2020-01-01') as startdate, convert(date, '2020-02-01') as enddate
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
     from calender_cte cc
     where startdate < enddate     
)
SELECT DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), -1) as 'WeekOf',
       DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), +5) as 'to',
       ISNULL(DATEPART(wk, inst.StartDate), 0) as 'WeekNumber'
FROM calender_cte cc LEFT JOIN
     [DESOutage].[dbo].[OPSInterruption] inst
     ON CC.startdate >=  inst.startdate and CC.startdate <= inst.enddate
Group by DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), -1),
         DATEPART(wk, inst.StartDate),
         DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, cc.StartDate), +5)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: When run this query and increse the range of date to one year 

It gives following error

Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @Learner. . . By default recursive cte has 100 recursion. If you have  more  then you can use query hint. See updated.

Comment: Hi @ yogesh-sharma, This works great but is not returning any data for weeks that have data. its returning everything as null

Comment: @Learner. .  You need to assign range in `ON` clause.

Comment: @ yogesh-sharma i actaully updated my query based on your suggestions and  I am not getting any data back for weeks even when there is data.